# PC freeze when installing Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, multi-boot, freeze, windows-installation

I bought all components for a new computer which has:

> MSI Z390 gaming edge ac as motherboard
>
> NVIDIA GTX 1660 3GB
>
> Two HDD 1Tb + 2Tb.

I intended to have a dual boot install (Windows 10 / Ubuntu) on my 1TB HDD and use the other 2TB to store data.

I started by ubuntu install because my Windows 10 bootable key wasn't ready.

The Ubuntu installation went all right but when I try to install Win10 my computer start to freeze, my mouse and keyboard doesn't respond anymore.

Sometimes the installation freeze at logo, sometime at dots loading and farest I could go was the disk partition part. At first I thought that maybe my windows ISO was corrupted, then I download many others, then I bought a new usb key and try other boot methods than unetbootin like diskpart and Rufus.

I thought about UEFI and legacy thing but ubuntu installation work everytime in UEFI and Windows seems to work in UEFI too but none of them work in legacy then I checked in my UEFI if Windows 10 installing was enabled and it was.

I don't really know what else to do, I don't know if i have to install in GPT or MBR, why UEFI only work for Ubuntu and if it's my Bios config that should be modified.

Anyone?

Comment: The [recommended order is](https://askubuntu.com/a/826329) to install Windows 10 first and then Ubuntu.

Comment: i already tried to format HDDs to reinstall , starting by Windows 10 by it's still the same

Comment: Well, you told you reached the disk partition part, what error does it pops out when you try to proceed the installation?

Comment: It doesn't pop any errors, While I'm setting my config the keyboard and mouse suddenly turn off and i can't do anything else. I tried to plug them on others usb ports but it doesn't work anymore until I reboot

Answer (score 1):

To resolve my problem I updated my BIOS, I searched how to flash my BIOS on MSI website and followed their explanations. Just had to download my update on my usb drive and reboot your computer, select your usb drive then select your updated file.